# How to more easily view the rear LCD?

Tags: accessories, rear-lcd

I was at work today and went for lunch, there was a professional photographer in kitchen using the following set up

Canon 5d
tripod
Canon tilt shift lens (not sure on the specifics)

The photographers was using live view to take his shots and kept placing a eye piece over the lcd live view finder. What is this peripheral called and where can I get one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are [LCD viewfinders](https://www.google.com/search?q=lcd+viewfinder). You can find a huge variety of prices and shapes, but they're all basically just a box to block light and make it easier for you to see the LCD screen without any reflections getting in the way.